# ListView Help JSON

Tags: android, json, android-listview, github

I have this JSON Array that I receive when I implement an HTTPGET request.
Then this is displayed in a textView as follows:

```
if(inputStream != null) {
            JSONArray reps = new JSONArray(convertInputStreamToString(inputStream));
            for (int i = 0; i < reps.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject item = (JSONObject) reps.get(i);
                result.append("\n(" + (i + 1) + ") " + item.get("name") + ":\n" + item.get("url") + "\n" + "Stars:" + item.get("stargazers_count") + "\n" + item.get("forks_count") + "\n");
            }
```

I want to view this in a list view but have failed so many attempts to do the same.
I am unable to create a viable adapter for it, so help on this is really appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a very basic list adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private JSONArray array;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private ViewHolder holder;

public ListAdapter(Context context, JSONArray array) {
    this.array = array;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView itemTV;
}

public int getCount() {
    return array.length();
}

public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
    try {
        return array.getJSONObject(position);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new JSONObject();
    }
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    holder = new ViewHolder();
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        holder.itemTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.itemTV.setText(getItem(position).get("name").toString());
    return view;

}
```

In your layout xml, add a ListView, such as:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Create a list item layout file. For this example, we'll just create a simple layout with one textview and save it as "item_layout.xml"...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/itemTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity, declare your listview and adapter, and once you get your JSON response, set the adapter...

```
private ListAdapter listAdapter;
private ListView listView;

...

listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

...

// do whatever you need to get your JSON response, then pass it to your adapter
// JSONArray reps = ....

listAdapter = new ListAdapter(context, reps);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

Comment: For a third party solution that provides the near equivalent of an ArrayAdapter for JSONArrays - https://github.com/JaySoyer/Advanced-Adapters